# Current milliseconds, from long to int

Tags: java

I currently have the following code:

```
public static int currentTimeMillis()
{
    long millisLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ( millisLong > Integer.MAX_VALUE )
    {
        millisLong -= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return (int)millisLong;
}
```

which returns the current time in an `int` format (not exactly, but it can be used for time differences). For very good reasons, I can't use `long`.

Yes, I am just interested in the difference between two calls, and this approach works well. But it just looks wrong. I know that. And inefficient. I know. So my questions is, how can I improve it?

I need a function that returns an `int` such that:

```
int x1 = currentTimeMillis(); //my function
long y1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

.....

int x2 = currentTimeMillis();
long y2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

// here, x2 - x1 must be equal to y2 - y1
```

EDIT:

FYI, I want to do this for benchmarking. I'm running tests on multiple threads in parallel, the stop event is triggered by an external component. I'm also serializing the data in a way that only supports `int`, and the object I'm serializing can not have `long` members.

Comment: It would be helpful to know *why* you want to do this. You've given us *what* you want and asked for *how* to do it, but without context, I just think "Why?"

Comment: @Dave I provided a summary explanation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your function does essentially the same as:

```
public static int currentTimeMillis() {
    return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

The above is probably what you're looking for. The [modulus operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator) `%` returns the remainder of the division. I would only wrap it in another class which hides this away. It's namely confusing to have "current time in millis" as an int with the wrong value. Something like:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.start();

// ...

int elapsed = stopwatch.elapsed();
```

with

```
public final class Stopwatch {

    private long start;

    private Stopwatch() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public static Stopwatch start() {
        return new Stopwatch();
    }

    public int elapsed() {
        return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

}
```

This is also much better in order to prevent problems when the start time is less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the end time is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which thus overflows back to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and continues from there.

Comment: I want to add, that if you are going to make a separate class for that, and only need a difference in time, then you should probably save the time as `long` but return the difference as `int` when needed, to be sure you won't get integer overflows anywhere.

Comment: @Max: I have in the meanwhile updated the answer with a concrete example.

Comment: I see, my comment got into heavy traffic jams.

Comment: The first option is perfect. I feel stupid for not thinking about it, I guess sometimes you just need a fresh view on things. I can't use the second one since... well... the stops are triggered by some events, multiple threads running in parallel... Thanks.

Comment: This overflows every 24 days at which point the difference will be incorrect.

Comment: @Peter: indeed, it will, but so will the OP's initial approach. You could add an additional check in `elapsed()` throwing an excpetion on that. I would however wonder why one would like to measure the elapsed time in millisecond precision on a task running for days.

Comment: If the time overflows between the start and the end (even if a few milli-seconds apart) it will be incorrect. Or you could use the solution I suggested which is simpler and doesn't have this problem. ;)

Comment: @Peter: yes you're right, that's a major problem. But yours has the same problem as well in the future. You'd really need the stopwatch approach.

Comment: As long as you take differences its is never a problem as the overflow/underflows cancel out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of finding a modulus, a much faster solution would be a simple bitwise mask operation:

```
public static int currentTimeMillis() {
    return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL);
}
```

Comment: Do you have benchmarks to show that this solution would be "much faster?"

Comment: @StriplingWarrior it's funny, I was 100% sure modulus is slow, but I forgot about compiler optimizations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues states that modulus from numbers that are `power of 2` can be optimized by using a bitwise AND operation. Which is essentially what I did. Well, less work for Java compiler I guess :P

Comment: Sure! On my computer the & operator is 1.25ns faster than the modulo calculation. That ought to be at least 3 or 4 CPU cycles. Who cares about code readability if you can make such vast optimizations? (If you find sarcasm, you can keep it).

Comment: @jarnbjo: I'm basking in the sarcasm. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that if the `currentTimeMillis` value rolls over the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` between taking `x1` and `x2`, you will end up with `x2 - x1` being a negative value. There are two ways to address this.

1. Use BalusC's approach, and then when you subtract `x2 - x1` check to see if it's negative. If it is, add `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to it again. (This assumes that no two time values will be checked that are actually more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` distance apart.)
2. Store the current time as a a private static value when the class is first initialized. From then on, make your function return the difference between the current time and that first startup time. This assumes that these time values will not need to persist when the system is restarted, and that the system will not be alive long enough to pass the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` mark.

As a side note, I'm sure we're all wondering what your very good reason is for not using `long` values?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to satisfy your condition 100% of the time because time can elapse between lines in your program during execution which will throw things off slightly. But the numbers won't be off by much. Without knowing more about your problem, I have to assume that you're not interested in the actual time. Perhaps you're just interested in elapsed time? Are you running some benchmarks? If elapsed time is all you need, the modulus solution suggested by @BalusC will do fine.

Comment: Agreed, but highly unlikely that the times will overlap.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
public static int currentTimeMillis() {
    return (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

If its negative it won't matter provided you take a difference. e.g.

```
int start = currentTimeMillis();

// will be positive for differences less than 24 days.
int time = currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Using this approach avoid the issue of overflows as they will cancel out e.g.

```
int start = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
// 1 ms later
int time = Integer.MIN_VALUE /*due to overflow*/ - start; 
// time equals 1 due to underflow.
```