# What is the solution of PendingIntent.getBroadcast method (int requestCode ) which I've long type value?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Now the problem is, I'm using primary id as System.currenttimemillis(), which obviously taking long type variable. Now based primary id, I'm setting  alarms, so that it will be unique also.

Now, when I'm type casting from long to int, I'm getting wrong value bacuse of larger number. So what should I do?

**NOTE:**
1. Please don't say to change my id to int, it's not possible.
2. Typecasting is not working.
3. I can't send same Id everytime, it's not possible now.

```
 public void createExactAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, long id) {
        AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, id);

        /*TODO:-> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is necessary to work in edit case*/
        showLog("In AR: " + (int) id);

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        /*TODO:-> set & setExact & setRepeating working in all cases*/
        mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mPendingIntent);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that "I'm using primary id as System.currenttimemillis()" is a good idea?

Comment: @CommonsWare it's not possible my boy. please don't discuss. because that is not in my hand.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244375/11555903) will help you